# How to Create Subapps in Nuxt. and Create Modular Deployment

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, code-structure

I am creating a Nuxt.js frontend/Express backend environment that will house multiple "sub" applications, for instance the structure currently looks like -

```
\-APP
\--Backend
\---public
\---routes
\---index.js
\--Frontend
\---components
\----App1Components
\----App2Components
\----App3Components
\----SharedComponents
\---layouts
\---pages
\----App1
\----App2
\----App3
\---nuxt.config.js
```

I want to be able to use the shared components within multiple apps, however when I want to publish App1, I want to only publish the changes in App1.

How do I separate these apps correctly on the deployment?

I know that this probably something that needs to be done in the nuxt.config.js or package.json files, but I do not know what to do.

Comment: Nuxt.js is primarily designed as a framework for building single-page applications (SPAs) and universal applications (SSR). So you can not directly create multiple app inside a nuxt project. You can do something like `Multiple Layouts`, `Routing and code splitting` or something like `different sub-domian while deploying`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will definitely have different subdomains, such as app1.apps.com and app2.apps.com, but ideally I would like to keep all of the apps in one environment and have reusable components, as well as components that are specific to each app and only get published to a specific subdomain.